# creating reports using asp.net on server

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, database, report

Can i use ReportViewer tool in VS2015 using Asp.net/c# to create reports working on server?

can anyone provide a good tutorial to learn using ReportViewer?

Or if there's any robust tool to create reports instead of crystal reports.

Answer (score 0):

By using Report Wizard, you can create reports in VS2015. This link will help you 
[Report Wizard in VS2015]
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/66489a/report-wizard-in-visual-studio-2015/

Comment: Ok, but my question now can i upload this report to work as an asp.net page?